# How to programmatically save a video to Photos with the specified Album?

Tags: swift, photo

I am developing an application that allows:

- Step 1: Select 1 video in Photos Album: Done.
- Step 2: Compress that video: Done.
- Step 3: Save the compressed video to Photo Album, in the same album as the original video.

I have completed step 1 and step 2 without any problem.
With step 3, I perform the following steps in turn:

- Step 3.1: Find out which album the original video is in: Done

  ```
  let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
  let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsContaining(fileAsset, with: albumType, options: fetchOptions)
  let assetCollection: PHAssetCollection = collection.firstObject
  ```
- Step 3.2: Save the compressed video to Photos: Done

  ```
  let creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
  creationRequest.addResource(with: .video, fileURL: videoURL, options: nil)
  ```
- Step 3.3: Put that video into PHAssetCollection in 3.1: Done

  ```
  let request = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: assetCollection)
  request.addAssets([creationRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset] as NSFastEnumeration)
  ```

All of the above steps have been completed. On my iPhone, the compressed video is in the same album as the original video. Perfectly!

**Problem**: On my Macbook the above compressed video is not in any Album. I can only find it under "Photos not in any albums". I wanted it to be in the album with the original uncompressed video.

My iPhone and my Macbook use the same iCloud, they sync with each other. Both iPhone and Macbook are set up to save the original file (full capacity) to the device from iCloud.

Some more info:

- My iPhone: iPhone XSMax, using iOS 14.5
- My Macbook: Macbook Pro late 2017, using Mac OS Big Sur 11.3
- Programming on: XCode 12.5

Many thanks if you help me to solve this problem. I spent a lot of time on it.